# can't update navigationbar when popping to root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITabBar`. In one tab is a `UINavigationController`. Let's say the 2nd or 3rd `UIViewController` in the stack has this:

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

If you click the current tab it will `popToRootViewController()` on the navigation controller. The problem is, in `viewWillDisappear(:)` of my current tab the `navigationController` is nil. So the navigationBar remains hidden.

What's the proper way to handle this? Should I just set the navigation bar to visible in the root view controller's `viewDidAppear`? That seems hacky.

Comment: You are using TabBarController?

Comment: Why don't just present view controller directly if you want to hide navigation bar.

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody else sees this, I don't know why the reference to `self.navigationController` gets set to nil before `viewWillDisappear` when you `popToRootViewController()` but a workaround I found was just to store your own reference to it.

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController {
    private weak var navCtrl: UINavigationController?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navCtrl = navigationController
        navCtrl?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navCtrl?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `override` the `viewWillAppear` in the `rootViewController` and `setNavigationBarHidden` from there. `navigationController` is `nil` at `viewDidDisappear` because it has already been popped off the navigation stack.